# Merge map values in list of maps cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a `List<Map>` with variable length that has the following structure:

```
[{name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ']}, {name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ', 'CREATE','UPDATE','DELETE']}, {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['READ']}]
```

I want to be able to write a Cypher query that returns a `List<Map>` with merged `crud` values when encountering the same `name` key, like so:

```
[{name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ', 'CREATE','UPDATE','DELETE']}, {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['READ']}]
```

---

Another example:

```
[{name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ']},{name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['UPDATE']}, {name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ','DELETE']}, {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['CREATE']}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ', 'DELETE']},{name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['UPDATE', 'CREATE']}]
```

I don't care about the order of the `crud` elements.

I am trying to sort it out using `apoc` procedures but to no avail so far.

Thanks to everyone who will try to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining an `UNWIND`, `COLLECT` and some of the `apoc` magic will get you there:

```
WITH 
[{name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ']},
 {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['UPDATE']}, 
 {name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ','DELETE']}, 
 {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['CREATE']}
] AS input
UNWIND input AS item
WITH {
        name:item.name,
        crud:apoc.coll.toSet(
               apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(item.crud)
               )
             )
       } AS item
RETURN COLLECT(item) AS output
```

returns the desired output

```
output
-----------
[
{
  "crud": [
    "READ",
    "DELETE"
  ],
  "name": "MANAGE_USERS"
}
,
{
  "crud": [
    "UPDATE",
    "CREATE"
  ],
  "name": "MANAGE_SITES"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without relying on `apoc` could be:

```
WITH 
[{name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ']},
 {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['UPDATE']}, 
 {name: 'MANAGE_USERS', crud: ['READ','DELETE']}, 
 {name: 'MANAGE_SITES', crud: ['CREATE']}
] AS input
UNWIND input AS item
WITH item['name'] AS name, item['crud'] AS crud
UNWIND crud AS action
WITH name, collect(DISTINCT action) AS actions 
RETURN collect({name: name, crud: actions}) AS output
```